# Word tables: Delete first row on the right without losing the text in left column

Tags: microsoft-word

The behavior of Word tables is whenever you delete the first row of the right column, you also lose the text in the left column (when the left column is merged). However, if you delete the 2nd, 3rd,...you still keep the text in left column.

I understand this default behavior is probably what user expected. However, I want to config in a way to keep the left text when deleting the first right row (see below image).

Thank you very much for your input.

Expected behavior:
[image: Expected behavior]